# modify conque to gate selected text

Tags: vimscript, plugin-conque

Via [Conque](https://code.google.com/p/conque/) I use vim as an IDE for all my coding. I am starting to work in python, which is persnickety about spacing, so to test deeply indented subroutines or code blocks, I need to gate code sent to the terminal with `%cpaste` and `--`. That is, if I am interactively editing and testing the following:

```
def wait_job(layer2, vault_name, job_id, sleepsec=60, timeout=86400):
    """ Wait for a job to terminate. """
    t0 = datetime.now()
    vault = fetch_vault(layer2, vault_name)
    while 1:
        job = vault.get_job(job_id)
        if not job.completed:
            tf = datetime.now()
            delta = tf - t0
            if (delta.seconds > timeout):
                # 2FIX: should this just return false?
                raise Exception('timed out')
            time.sleep(sleepsec)
        else:
            break
    wasok = job.completed
    return wasok
```

And grab the code block starting from `if not job.completed`, and send it to an ipython process in a Conque window, I have to send:

```
%cpaste
        if not job.completed:
            tf = datetime.now()
            delta = tf - t0
            if (delta.seconds > timeout):
                # 2FIX: should this just return false?
                raise Exception('timed out')
            time.sleep(sleepsec)
        else:
            break
--
```

I believe I have to modify the following line in the definition of `ConqueTerm_SendVisKey`:

```
if maparg(g:ConqueTerm_SendVisKey, 'v') == ''
  sil exe 'v' . map_modifier . 'map <silent> ' . g:ConqueTerm_SendVisKey . ' :<C-u>call conque_term#send_selected(visualmode())<CR>'
endif
```

But am not sure where to start. Probably it would be better to define variables for gate start and gate end, but can I just do a string concat around `visualmode()`? Or must I send call the send three times?

Comment: Not sure I understood your question because I know nothing about python, Conque or IPython. So I'm going to try and reformulate it with my words. You've got a key whose value is stored in the global variable `g:ConqueTerm_SendVisKey`, let's say `<F9>`. When you visually select some text and hit on this key, it's sent to some other process, which is what you want. But sometimes you want to send something slightly different: `%cpaste` + `visually selected text` + `--`. Is it what you want?

Comment: @saginaw that is it exactly; since I use `<F9>` everywhere, I would prefer to set a text prefix and suffix (empty by default) which are _always_ added to the payload, and then set them by filetype. I admit, however, I don't even know how to do basic string concatenation or interpolation in vimscript.

Comment: Not sure, but you could try this. In your vimrc add this autocmd: `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * if &ft ==# 'python' | let [b:gate_start, b:gate_end] = ["%cpaste\n", "\n--"] | else | let [b:gate_start, b:gate_end] = ["", ""] | endif`
 It will set the value for the prefix/suffix. Next, in the code of the `send_selected()` function inside your Conque plugin, there must be a line like this: ```sil exe "normal! `<" . a:type . "`>y"``` This line copies your visually selected text which is now inside the unnamed register `@@`.

Comment: Just after this line, you could try to add the following line, which hopefully will do the concatenation: `let @@ = b:gate_start . @@ . b:gate_end`

Comment: Assuming you're using this Conque plugin (https://github.com/vim-scripts/Conque-Shell), here is the line after which you must do the concatenation: https://github.com/vim-scripts/Conque-Shell/blob/master/autoload/conque_term.vim#L1227

Comment: @saginaw I forked the repo and modified it as follows: https://github.com/shabbychef/Conque-Shell/blob/master/autoload/conque_term.vim#L1235-L1238. Any reason I couldn't use a global variable like `g:ConqueTerm_SuffixString`?

Comment: It depends on how you intend to define your variables (through an autocmd, inside the called function ...). Maybe the simplest way would be to test the filetype of the current buffer inside the function `send_selected()`, set the values of the prefix/suffix accordingly, and finally do the concatenation. Something like this: http://vpaste.net/UN0m3 When you define a variable inside a function, it's local to the latter by default, no need of a scope. Does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to get this behaviour *without* changing ConqueTerm's code itself. The code below applies your desired behaviour to linewise visual mode selections*.

It works by adding the gates to the buffer, sending the whole lot over to ConqueTerm (using the same code that ConqueTerm itself uses in its mapping), and then removing the gates again.

You can add the code to your .vimrc, or if you want it only to apply to Python files, you could add `<buffer>` to the `vnoremap` mapping to make it buffer-specific and put it in `.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` so it applies to all Python files:

```
vnoremap <silent> <f9> :<c-u>call ConqueWrapper("%cpaste", "--")<CR>

function! ConqueWrapper(start_gate, end_gate)
  let m = visualmode()

  " Only apply this wrapper to linewise selections
  if m ==# 'V'
    let start_line = line("'<")
    let end_line = line("'>")

    " Add in the code gates
    call append(end_line, a:end_gate)
    call append(start_line - 1, a:start_gate)

    " Reset the visual marks
    call setpos("'<", [0, start_line, 0, 0])
    call setpos("'>", [0, end_line + 2, 0, 0])

    " Send to ConqueTerm
    call conque_term#send_selected("V")

    " Switch back to original buffer
    wincmd p

    " Remove the code gates
    execute end_line + 2 . "delete _"
    execute start_line . "delete _"

    " Switch back to ConqueTerm
    wincmd p
  else
    " Not linewise: just pass it on directly to ConqueTerm
    execute "call conque_term#send_selected(\"" . m . "\")"
  endif
endfunction
```

My personal preference is not to make changes to the source code of plugins if I can avoid it, because then you have to either:

1. Make a fork of plugin project, and keep this updated by merging in future changes from the original project,
2. Or reapply your changes every time you update the plugin.

...neither of which is a very appealing prospect.

<sub>* Because I don't think it makes much sense for characterwise or blockwise selections, and the code to implement it would be more complicated, and therefore harder for you to understand.</sub>

Comment: I would share your concern, however it seems that `vim-conque` has not been updated in 5 years (_cf_ http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771 ). So I am not terribly worried about having to merge in changes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure I fully understand the problem you are having or what you are trying to achieve.  From what I can gather, you're trying to interactively execute python code from vim.  If you're willing to entertain non-Conque related solutions, then I'd highly recommend the vim-ipython plugin.  It allows you to select arbitrary lines of python code and execute them in an existing ipython session.  I believe it is fairly forgiving about the indentation as long as the selected block is correctly indented within itself.  This should allow you to select just the `if` block within a function and execute it even though it may be indented a few levels relative to the rest of the file (hopefully that made sense).

The plugin can be found here: https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython

Comment: thanks for the tip, but I use Conque ubiquitously for dev work in _many_ languages (R, matlab, bash, MySQL, _etc_) and am hoping to avoid context switching for the sake of one language.

Comment: The problem to be solved as I see it is to modify the `maparg ... sil exe` bits (and vimscript is Greek to me) to accept an optional prefix and postfix (which I can define based on filetype) that would contain the gate strings _viz_ `%cpaste` and so on.

Comment: @shabbychef The line you're referring to simply defines a mapping. The mapping tells Vim that whenever you hit on `<F9>` in visual mode, it must call the function `send_selected()`. So you must not modify the mapping but the function which is defined here: https://github.com/vim-scripts/Conque-Shell/blob/master/autoload/conque_term.vim#L1220-L1244 The line 1227 copies your visual selection in the unnamed register `@@`. You can concatenate your variables `gate_start` and `gate_end` just after it.